# Expected value of random variable that is defined by another

Tags: probability, self-study, expected-value

Suppose I have a random variable:

\begin{equation}
X \sim
\begin{cases}
1 \text{ with probability } p \\
y \sim \mathit{unif}(1,k) \text{ with probability } 1 - p
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Where $\mathit{unif}$ is the discrete uniform distribution. I am trying to compute the expected value $E[X].$ I think it should just be simply:

\begin{equation}
1 \cdot p + E[y] \cdot (1-p) = 1 \cdot p + (1 + k)/2 \cdot (1-p)
\end{equation}

But I am not sure if I am overlooking something.

Comment: The given answers are both correct for calculating the answer in your concrete problem. I would add, however, that in a general case, you would apply conditional probabilities. For discrete distributions, and naming the random variable that $X$ depends on $Z$, we get: $$\mathbb{P}(X = k)=\sum_{z\in\text{supp}(Z)} \mathbb{P}(X = k | Z = z) \mathbb{P}(Z=z)$$ (law of total probability). This you can then evaluate further (in this concrete example, of course, the sum is only over two values), and in particular evaluate the expectation via $\sum_k k \mathbb{P}(X=k)$.

Comment: Hi. I'm used to notation $y \sim \mathit{unif}(\text{some set})$ for the uniform distribution on a given set, but I've never encountered notation $y \sim \mathit{unif}(1,k)$. I don't know what the $1$ and $k$ parameters mean in your case. Could you please explain? From the expected value calculation I can guess that it's maybe the uniform distribution on closed segment $\left[1,k\right]$, or on open segment $\left]1,k\right[$, or on the two-element set $\{1, k\}$, or something else...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your random variable takes the value $1$ with probability $p+\frac{1-p}{k}$, and takes each value $j\in\{2, \dots, k\}$ with probability $\frac{1-p}{k}$. So the expectation is simply
$$ \begin{align*} EX
= & 1\times \big(p+\frac{1-p}{k}\big) + \sum_{j=2}^k j\times\frac{1-p}{k} \\ 
= & p+\frac{1-p}{k}\times \sum_{j=1}^k j \\
= & p+\frac{1-p}{k}\times\frac{k(k+1)}{2} \\
= & p+\frac{(1-p)(k+1)}{2}.
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 10):

Your answer is okay and is justified below.

You can  write:$$X=B+(1-B)Y$$where $B\sim\text{Bernoulli}(p)$ and $Y\sim\text{Unif}(k)$ are independent random variables.

Then:$$\mathbb EX=\mathbb EB+\mathbb E[(1-B)Y]=\mathbb EB+\mathbb E(1-B)\mathbb EY=p+(1-p)\left(\frac12+\frac12k\right)$$

This way of working is recommendable in situations where the rv is defined by means of cases.